# React-Hooks PUT request a specific field from an object on click

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, react-hooks

How can I make a PUT request and target ONLY patient.status and change it from Active to Inactive? I don't want to change the entire patient, only the patient.status.

Keep in mind I want to use fetch(), I just do not know the syntax on how to only edit patient.status and pass it through my backend, etcetera. Help would be appreciated.

I am fetching data from a specific patient this way and declaring state.

```
const [patient, setPatient] = useState ({})

useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`/api/patients/${match.params.id}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => setPatient(json))

}, [patient])
```

The submit function.

```
const onDeactivePatientSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
}
```

The button.

```
     { patient.status === "Active" &&
      <Button size="small" color="primary" variant="outlined" onClick={onDeactivePatientSubmit} 
value="Inactive">DE-ACTIVATE PATIENT</Button>
            }
```

The backend. (Please keep in mind I want to keep the req.body.editPatient as is)

```
router.put('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const {id} = req.params;
    await Patient.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {...req.body.editPatient});
    console.log(req.body.editPatient)
    res.status(200).send({});
})
```

Comment: can we get a sample of all properties of patient object ? And is the active/inactive already existing or you need to add this property to the object ?

Comment: patient.status: "Active" gets assigned automatically to the backend when someone creates a new patient, as well as the state. these are the following properties in patient object:     fullName, age, admissionDate, exitDate, condition, upcomingSurgeries, status, diagnosis, supervisor, notes (array), prescription (array). In regards to patient.status, it gets assigned to state through useEffect. So it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetch` accepts a second parameter, an [options object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Supplying_request_options), where you can set the method you want to use, the data to send, etc. You can use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to create a new/updated patient object. It will make a copy of the fetched `patient` object, and you can update the `status` field. You can send this new object via `fetch`:

```
const onDeactivePatientSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  
  let updatedPatient = {
    ...patient,
    status: 'Inactive',
  }

  fetch(`/api/patients/${patient.id}`, {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    // the data to send
    body: JSON.stringify({ editPatient: updatedPatient })
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    // check if successfully updated in db
    setPatient(updatedPatient)
}
```